# Difference between hypotenuse and larger leg in a Pythagorean triple

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, pythagorean-triples

I've been number crunching irreducible Pythagorean triples and this pattern came up: the difference between the hypotenuse and the larger leg seems to always be *n*² or 2*n*² for some integer *n*. Moreover, every integer of the form *n*² or 2*n*² is the difference between hypotenuse and the larger leg for *some* irreducible Pythagorean triple. Is there a simple proof for that?

There is a result listed on Wikipedia that looks kinda, sorta related: that the area of a Pythagorean triangle can *not* be the square or twice the square of a natural number.

EDIT: Actually, the statements are correct only for *odd* *n*² (but also by any 2*n*² as stated) as John Omielan demonstrated below.

Comment: Are you aware of the formula $(p^2-q^2, 2pq, p^2+q^2)$ where $p,q$ are coprime and have opposite parity?

Comment: By the way, what is an example of an irreducible Pythagorean triple in which the difference between the hypotenuse and larger leg is $2^2$?

Comment: @DavidK The difference of 4 is impossible as proved in the answers below.

Comment: Yes, that was a hint that the $n^2$ differences would occur only for odd $n.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in [Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple), for integers $m \gt n \gt 0$, Euclid's formula of

$$a = m^2 - n^2, \; \; b = 2mn, \; \; c = m^2 + n^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

generates all primitive (i.e., irreducible) Pythagorean triples, specifically

> *Every* primitive triple arises (after the exchange of $a$ and $b$, if $a$ is even) from a *unique pair* of coprime numbers $m$, $n$, one of which is even.

Note \eqref{eq1A} results in

$$c - a = (m^2 + n^2) - (m^2 - n^2) = 2n^2 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

$$c - b = (m^2 + n^2) - 2mn = (m - n)^2 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Regarding your second part, to help avoid confusion with $n$ above, let's call the values $k^2$ and $2k^2$ instead. With the first one, it uses \eqref{eq3A} so $k = m - n$. However, since one of $m$ and $n$ is even and the other is odd, their difference is odd, so only odd $k$ will work. For any such $k$, set $n = k + 1$ and $m = 2k + 1$ (note $m$ and $n$ are coprime, with $n$ even) to get

$$m^2 - n^2 = (4k^2 + 4k + 1) - (k^2 + 2k + 1) = 3k^2 + 2k \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

$$2mn = 2(2k + 1)(k + 1) = 2(2k^2 + 3k + 1) = 4k^2 + 6k + 2 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

This shows $2mn \gt m^2 - n^2$, so $2mn$ is the longer leg. Thus, the difference would result in \eqref{eq3A}.

For the $2k^2$ case, choose $n = k$ and $m = 3k + 1$ (note $m$ and $n$ are coprime, with one of them even). Therefore,

$$m^2 - n^2 = (9k^2 + 6k + 1) - k^2 = 8k^2 + 6k + 1 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

$$2mn = 2(3k + 1)k = 6k^2 + 2k \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

This means $m^2 - n^2 \gt 2mn$, so $m^2 - n^2$ is the longer leg. Thus, the difference would result in \eqref{eq2A}.

Comment: +1: (also) to your answer, as presenting a more complete answer to the question than my answer did.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks for the response & upvote. I was about to press the Post button with just the first part answered, similar to your answer, when I happened to look at the question again to notice it had a second part as well. So I also missed that part initially.

Comment: You also proved my statement is wrong. Not all squares can be the "personality" (I'm calling [c - larger leg] that) of a primitive Pythagorean triple. The double of any square can and is, though.

Comment: Also, the statement applies to both c-a and c-b regardless of which is the "personality" (i.e., the largest).

Answer (score 3):

Counter example is $(9, 12, 15)$.

**Edit**
In addition to overlooking the 2nd part of the OP's question, as indicated in my 2nd edit (below), I also overlooked that in the first part of the OP's question, he is (also) specifically focusing on irreducible Pythagorean triplets.

> I've been number crunching irreducible Pythagorean triples

However, if the pythagorean triplet is presumed irreducible, then the problem is completely resolved by [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) which indicates that the product will either have form

$[(m^2 + n^2) - (m^2 - n^2)] = 2n^2$

or will have form

$[(m^2 + n^2) - (2mn)] = (m - n)^2.$

**Edit**
After reading John Omielan's answer, and then re-reading the question, I realized that my answer **is incomplete**.  However, there is no point in my trying to complete my answer, since John Omielan's answer covers the exact same ground.

Answer (score 1):

We have $a^2+b^2=c^2$, hence $(c-b)(c+b)=a^2$. Since the triple is irreducible, the GCD of $c-b$ and $c+b$ is at most $2$: any divisor of both $c-b$ and $c+b$ would also have to be a divisor of $(c+b)-(c-b)=2b$, and $GCD(c-b, b)=GCD(c+b,b)=GCD(b,c)=1$. So we can say the following about $c-b$ and $c+b$:

- The product of these two numbers is a square. That is, the power of each prime factor of their product is even.
- The two numbers do not share any prime factors apart from, possibly, $2$.

This means that, with a possible exception of $2$, every prime factor's power of both $c-b$ and $c+b$ is even. If the numbers are odd (their GCD is 1), the same holds for $2$ (its power is $0$), so each of them is a perfect square. If the numbers are even (their GCD is 2), divide both by $2$ first, and then similarly conclude that $(c-b)/2$ as well as $(c+b)/2$ is a square.

As for the second part of the question, just find any solution to either $c-b=n^2$ or $c-b=2n^2$ for an arbitrary $n$. In particular, the triples $(n^2+2n, 2n+2, n^2+2n+2)$ and $(2n^2+2n, 2n+1, 2n^2+2n+1)$ respectively satisfy the condition.

Note though that for even $n$ there are no *irreducible* triples with $c-b=n^2$: since $c+b$ has to be a square of the same parity, both $c-b$ and $c+b$ are divisible by $4$, then $2b=(c+b)-(c-b)$ and $2c=(c+b)+(c-b)$ are divisible by $4$, which means $b$, $c$, and consequently $a$ are all even.

Answer (score 0):

If we replace the usual $(m,n)$ of Euclid's formula with
$(2n-1+k,k)$, we get
\begin{align*}
  A=(2n-1)^2+                     & 2(2n-1)k      \\ 
  B=  \qquad\quad\quad   & 2(2n-1)k+ 2k^2\\ 
  C=(2n-1)^2+                    & 2(2n-1)k+ 2k^2\\
\end{align*}
which produces the mostly-primitve table of Pythagorean triples below. Notice that half of  all triples have $A>B$ and half have $B>A$.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & k=5   \\ \hline
Set_1 & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13& 7,24,25& 9,40,41& 11,60,61  \\ \hline
Set_2 & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65 & 39,80,89 \\ \hline
Set_3 & 35,12,37 & 45,28,53 &55,48,73 &65,72,97 &  75,100,125  \\ \hline
Set_{4} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 &91,60,109 &105,88,137 &119,120,169  \\ \hline
Set_{5} &99,20,101 &117,44,125 &135,72,153 &153,104,185 &171,140,221  \\ \hline
Set_{6} &43,24,145 &165,52,173 &187,84,205 &209,120,241 &231,160,281  \\ \hline
\end{array}

From the formula we can see that $\quad C-A=2k^2\quad$ and that $\quad C-B=(2n-1)^2.\quad $ The first case it is twice the square of any natural number and the second is an odd number squared.